# Disable cookies on page load with Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a webpage with third-party cookies and I'm trying to disable them on page load with Javascript. This is my code:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function()
{
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    console.log("cookies = " + cookies);

    for (var i = 0 ; i < cookies.length; i++) 
    {
        var cookie_name = cookies[i].split("=")[0];
        document.cookie = cookie_name + "=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT; domain=localhost;";
        console.log(cookie_name + " disabled");
    }
});
```

The first time the page is accessed, no cookies are found by the script, but the third-party cookies are installed (I've found them by inspecting via EditThisCookie plugin for Chrome). If I reload the page, cookies are found by the script, but I noticed they have been installed again.

It seems like cookies are installed after the script execution, so I'm not able to catch them after installation. How can I effectively manage to disable these cookies?

Comment: The third-party cookies is created with js or is created for the server languaje (PHP for example)

Answer (score 1):

you can this.

```
setCookie(cookie_name, "disabled", -1);
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
```

reference: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp